# Is it safe to use same host volume in multiple containers?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Can I safely use same named data volume from multiple containers at the same time? Meaning, can I do following:

```
docker run -v data_disk:/data base/archlinux
docker run -v data_disk:/data ubuntu
```

without fear of data corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always - it depends :)
In this case on the application as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/important-tips-on-using-shared-volumes)

> Multiple containers can also share one or more data volumes. However,
>   multiple containers writing to a single shared volume can cause data
>   corruption. Make sure your applications are designed to write to
>   shared data stores.

Comment: so... if I understand it correctly, there is no additional caching etc. on container boundary? So as long as the combination of tools/programs working over same volume works fine when running on one system, they should work fine when each running in own container?

Comment: to my knowledge docker won't introduce additional caching, but of course if you use a volume driver plugin and attach a SMB share as volume then those specific driver's may cache by themselves

Comment: so with plain old `-v name:/path` it should be fine, thanks :)